# Multiuser login in different browsers

Tags: ajax, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

How to store user details on browser session and retrieve using Rails application when I logged in with different browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ruby devise gem for integration of signup/signin/logout functionality.

For more details, go to the link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: When I login into a rails application using chrome browser, then I login into another account using Firefox browser. At the same time I refresh the chrome browser, 2nd login details shown in the chrome browser. How can I solve this problem? And I'm using (devise_security_extension) gem

Comment: Thanks and trying..  Its works on local but not works on server.